# Is it possible to use a gesture to go back in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, multi-touch

I miss the ability to go back to previous directory via a gesture (swipe with two finger right like in Safari or Chrome) in Finder. Is it possible to enable it?

*Edit: I'm on a MacBook Pro, and using the trackpad.*

Comment: Upvoted as there is no need for a down vote, a comment with a future edit will do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***UPDATE***

<del>*It looks like this has been broken in Mac OS X 10.9 (and wasn't fixed in 10.9.1)*</del>

This works again in the latest Mac Os X 10.10.1, and presumably also in 10.10.

**Trackpad**
Three-finger swipe left goes back and forth in Finder, just like in Safari. 
You don't need 3rd party software to do this, simply make sure your settings are correct.

Go to `System Preferences` via Spotlight or Launchpad, navigate to `Trackpad` and click the tab `More Gestures`. The first option is "Swipe between pages", which enables swiping in Finder, Chrome etc. Make sure to choose one of the two `Swipe` options.

I've attached an image showing the screen for you here:
[image: Swipe between pages]

Make sure that you've chosen `Swipe left or right with four fingers` in the `Swipe between full-screen apps` so the two options don't overrule each other.
[image: Swipe between full-screen apps]

You also want to make sure there is no checkmark in the `Three finger drag`. They are mutually exclusive. You can check this in the `Point & Click` tab.
[image: Three finger drag]

**Magic Mouse**
If you use a Magic Mouse and want to be able to swipe back and forth in Finder, you have to turn off the `Swipe between full-screen apps` and change `Swipe between pages` to either `Swipe left or right with two fingers` or `Swipe left or right with one or two fingers` (both options enables you to swipe back and forth in Finder when using *both* fingers.
[image: Swipe back and forth with Magic Mouse in Finder]

Comment: That may work for a trackpad, but I can't get it to work with a magic mouse.  `Swipe Between Pages` option, which uses just one finger (no option for 3-finger gesture), allows for gestures in Safari, Preview, etc, but not in Finder.

Comment: I'm updating the answer to provide more information, which might resolve your problem.

@cm2: The question didn't mention whether it was with a trackpad or a magic mouse.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Lion.

Comment: OK, I got it working. The reason it didn't work in my test was because the Finder window need to have focus and there is no visual feedback until the directory change (while there is feedback in Safari for example). Thank you, response accepted.

Comment: @MatiasVad: Correct, but I was just adding more feedback to make it more general :).  Nice answer.

Comment: It looks like this is broken in Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks)

Comment: @recklesscoder is, unfortunately, seems you are right. I just tested in the latest update 10.9.1, and it is still broken. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Still works in 10.12.5. Great answer, very detailed :)

Comment: It doesn't work on 10.13.2 High Sierra

Comment: @LucioMollinedo I can confirm that it works in High Sierra 10.13.2. Nothing has changed. Please check your settings again :)

Comment: I just tested again. WORKS: Swipe with THREE fingers. DOESN'T WORK: Swipe with two or three fingers (only swiping with three fingers work if you choose this option).

I don't want to swipe with three fingers only there if the two finger swiping works perfectly well everywhere else.

Comment: In case three finger swipe for back/forward isn't working for you, make sure three finger drag isn't enabled in Settings > Accessibility > Mouse and Trackpad > Trackpad Options.

Comment: This works, but the swipe direction is reversed in Finder than it is in Safari... Why did Apple do this? (Safari: Swipe from left to right to go back | Finder: Swipe from right to left to go back)

Comment: @LucasP. indeed, enabling the `swipe` rather than `scroll` reverses the direction. This is super weird. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 9):

With [BetterTouchTool](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=bettertouchtool&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://blog.boastr.net/&ei=BzDdTpHjD4uF-wa3l-jQBA&usg=AFQjCNFI1XGihvXQaXEMz4TpptQpfVgOgw), (almost) everything is possible! :)
You can, for any application, map a gesture to a keyboard shortcut.
You will then be able to attach Cmd+[ to the two finger left swipe gesture.