# Mojave scroll left/right not working properly for native apps

Tags: trackpad, macos, mojave

I updated my mac to macOS Mojave and I am facing problems for native apps when I scroll left or right, for instance:

- On Safari, I can't go to the previous page scrolling to the left (works on Chrome)
- I can't dismiss pop-up notifications
- "swipe menus" for Mail, for instance, are not accessible

I tried to tick/untick the Trackpad settings, didn't work.

[image: Trackpad Settings]

Comment: Apparently, you have to make it two or three finger swipe (the next option on the list)  and it works. This removes the possibility to drag windows using three fingers through (which I personally use all the time). https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/is-it-possible-to-use-a-gesture-to-go-back-in-finder